# I can use mono in Windows 7 for developing applications for iPhone

Tags: ios4

I can use mono in Windows 7 for developing applications for iPhone. What I have to install?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for the installation process: http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation

It is not possible to run this on Windows, you need MacOS.

However, some parts (Business layer...) could be developed independently on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. MonoTouch (the tools and libraries on top of Mono that can be used to build iPhone apps) depends on the iPhone SDK, which runs on Mac OS X only.